# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.map')

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux

I am trying to change the state of my 'quantityCounter' but I'm getting an error as the title says. Can anyone help me with changing the state while the value also changes in the screen?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectCartItems } from '../../../../redux/reducer/cartReducer';
import { selectAllItems } from '../../../../redux/reducer/itemReducer';

const CartList = () => {
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const itemData = useSelector(selectAllItems);
  
  const [quantityCounter, setQuantityCounter] = React.useState(cartItems);

  function quantityHandler({id, num}){
    const targetItem = itemData.find((item) => item.id === id);
    let targetCart = quantityCounter.find((cart) => cart.id === id);

    setQuantityCounter((previousState) => 
      previousState.forEach(
        (item) => {
          if(item.id === id){
            Object.keys(item).find(key => {
              if(key === 'quantity'){
                if(num === 1 && targetCart.quantity < targetItem.availableItem){
                  item[key] = targetCart.quantity + 1;
                }
                if(num === 0 && targetCart.quantity > 0) {
                  item[key] = targetCart.quantity - 1;
                }
              }
            })
          }
      }));
  }
  return (
    <>
    {quantityCounter.map((item) => (
      <View style={styles.CartItemsContainer} key={item.id}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.productName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.productPrice}</Text>
        <View style={styles.quantityContainer}>
          <Button title='-' onPress={() => quantityHandler({id : item.id, num: 0})}/>
          <Text style={styles.quantityContainer__text}>{item.itemQuantity}</Text>
          <Button title='+' onPress={() => quantityHandler({id : item.id, num: 1})}/>
        </View>
      </View>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  CartItemsContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  textStyle: {
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer:{
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'baseline', justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer__text:{
    marginHorizontal: 5, marginVertical: 5
  }
});
export default CartList;
```

Another approach I did was this but the state is only changing, in the screen it doesn't. When the 'quantityHandler' is being pressed, it works as what it is supposed to be but I don't know how to fix or make this work. I tried different way but I can't really show it. Please help.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectCartItems } from '../../../../redux/reducer/cartReducer';
import { selectAllItems } from '../../../../redux/reducer/itemReducer';

const CartList = () => {
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
  const itemData = useSelector(selectAllItems);
  const [quantityCounter, setQuantityCounter] = React.useState(0);
  let total = 0;
  let id, quantity, name, price;
  let cart_replica = [];
  cartItems.forEach(item => {
    id = item.id;
    name = item.productName;
    price = item.productPrice;
    quantity = item.itemQuantity;
    total += item.totalPrice;
    cart_replica.push({id, name, quantity, price})
  });

  function quantityHandler({id, num}){
    const targetItem = itemData.find((item) => item.id === id);
    let targetCart = cart_replica.find((cart) => cart.id === id);
    cart_replica.map(
      (item) => {
        if(item.id === id){
          return { ...cart_replica, item: { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1}};
        }
    });
    console.log(cart_replica[0])

  }
  return (
    <>
    {cart_replica.map((item) => (
      <View style={styles.CartItemsContainer} key={item.id}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.price}</Text>
        <View style={styles.quantityContainer}>
          <Button title='-' onPress={() => quantityHandler({id : item.id, num: 0})}/>
          <Text style={styles.quantityContainer__text}>{item.quantity}</Text>
          <Button title='+' onPress={() => quantityHandler({id : item.id, num: 1})}/>
        </View>
      </View>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  CartItemsContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  textStyle: {
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer:{
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'baseline', justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer__text:{
    marginHorizontal: 5, marginVertical: 5
  }
});
export default CartList;
```

Comment: please share an expo snack? will check there

Comment: This is my first time using this, full of errors when I import all my things from here: https://snack.expo.dev/@git/github.com/daryledevs/e_commerce_app?platform=android

Comment: just add only the code which is required and can you please solve the issue?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the wait. Here is the link for this: https://snack.expo.dev/3JHyY-OXf Thank you so much!

Comment: hey, whats crashing? cant see any crashes here

Comment: When I clicked the button with plus sign, the value from state does change, which increased, but from the screen is not.

Comment: okay lemme check , you have added reducer right?

Comment: From the expo snack, I didn't. I can work on the rest, I just need badly how to change things from quantityHandler to change the state as well as the values from the screen, updates automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this ,ive added state manipulation.

Hope it helps :)

https://snack.expo.dev/5vfUoenH3

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [quantityCounter, setQuantityCounter] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'item 1',
      availableItem: 5,
      price: 500,
      quantity: 5,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'item 2',
      availableItem: 4,
      price: 500,
      quantity: 4,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'item 3',
      availableItem: 3,
      price: 500,
      quantity: 3,
    },
  ]);


  const  quantityHandler = (id,index,isIncrement) =>{

  const newCopy = [...quantityCounter];
  if(isIncrement){
newCopy[index].quantity = newCopy[index].quantity +1;
  }else {
   
newCopy[index].quantity = newCopy[index].quantity -1;
  }

      console.log("er",newCopy,index)

  setQuantityCounter(newCopy)
  }
  


  
  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeStyle}>
    {quantityCounter.map((item,index) => (
      <View style={styles.CartItemsContainer} key={item.id}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.price}</Text>
        <View style={styles.quantityContainer}>
          <Button title='-' onPress={() => quantityHandler(item.id,index,false)}/>
          <Text style={styles.quantityContainer__text}>{item.quantity}</Text>
          <Button title='+' onPress={() => quantityHandler(item.id,index,true)}/>
        </View>
      </View>
      ))}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeStyle: {
    marginTop:'5%'
  }, 
  CartItemsContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  textStyle: {
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer:{
    flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 1, borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'baseline', justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  quantityContainer__text:{
    marginHorizontal: 5, marginVertical: 5
  }
});
export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to give a like but my reputation is slow haha! Anyways, thank you so much!!

Comment: @AlmightyDee hey, you can give a like now if it helped 

Comment: Nice, finally! Thank you again! LIKED! ^^